# Change the date in R and put it into condition

Tags: r, date

If have two columns with dates in my dataset. Now I want them to have the same format. The first one looks like this: yyyymmdd (so, January 1st 2015 is 20150101) and the second one looks like this: dd/mm/yyyy (so, January 1st 2015 is 01/01/2015). Anyone who can help me with that?

Because after that I want to have a condition that a third column gives the value 1 if the year of both dates are the same or if one is earlier than the other one.

Hope anyone can help me out!

Comment: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/dates-and-times.html might help

Comment: or this https://epirhandbook.com/en/working-with-dates.html#messy-dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how we could solve this:

We could use `parse_date_time()` function from `lubridate` package. It is important to use the `orders` argument as desired so what is first year or month etc.. and
all should be wrapped around `ymd()` to get date without hours and minutes:

```
library(tibble)

# example data
df<- tibble( x_date = "20150101",
        y_date= "01/01/2015")


library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("date"), ~ymd(parse_date_time(., orders = c('ymd', 'dmy')))))
```

```
  x_date     y_date    
  <date>     <date>    
1 2015-01-01 2015-01-01
```